# How to display user details using popover bootstrap without using click event bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I work on razor page asp.net .I face issue I can't show user details using mouse or popover without using bootstrap modal

what i do as below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetailsModal">
View User Details
    </button>
```

modal bootstrap used to display user details

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="userDetailsModalLabel">User Details</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><strong>User Name:</strong> @TempData["UserName"]</p>
                    <p><strong>User Role:</strong> @TempData["UserRole"]</p>
                    <p><strong>Environment:</strong> @TempData["Environment"]</p>
                    <p><strong>User ID:</strong> @TempData["UserId"]</p>
                    <p><strong>StatusCode:</strong> @TempData["StatusCode"]</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I pass user details using temp data from model to view and data passed success

**Image to what I expect to do :**

[image: image to picture what I need to do]

**Updated Post**

can you apply popover for sample code attached

Comment: Have you looked into popovers? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#enable-popovers

Comment: can you please help me by apply popover on sample code i attached

Comment: i updated original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, You are using `Boostrap 4` modal to show the data, But now Asp.Net Core is using `Boostrap 5`. There are some different in code between `Boostrap 4` and `Boostrap 5`, You can update your code to :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#userDetailsModal">
    View User Details
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="userDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="userDetailsModalLabel">User Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><strong>User Name:</strong> @TempData["UserName"]</p>
                <p><strong>User Role:</strong> @TempData["UserRole"]</p>
                <p><strong>Environment:</strong> @TempData["Environment"]</p>
                <p><strong>User ID:</strong> @TempData["UserId"]</p>
                <p><strong>StatusCode:</strong> @TempData["StatusCode"]</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```